# Situation where inline expansion may not work?

Tags: c++

I have read somewhere that for functions not returning values, if a return statement exists inline expansion may not work.

Can anybody tell me the exact reason for this?

Comment: Way too vague - please cite the source and the exact wording.

Comment: Its written in Object Oriented Programming in c++ by Balaguruswamy.Wording is exact.

Comment: @avinashpandey: Is that really the exact wording? The sentence is nonsensical as far as I can tell. Is the sentence talking about `void` functions? Does the book provide some kind of code example to illustrate this? Can you show a paragraph containing this sentence?

Comment: It never mentioned the return type of function but just said "Functions not returning any value".I guess it is void.

Comment: Indian text books such as this (and others by Kanetkar) tend to be very out-of-date, inaccurate and of poor quality - even the latest edition (2013) of this particular book is still using Turbo C++ and `<iostream.h>` etc. You would be better off getting more up-to-date books from reputable authors.

Comment: @PaulR Thanks for the advice.Any suggestion for other books.

Comment: @avinashpandey: there's a [useful list right here on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1):

The `inline` keyword is more of a hint to the compiler than an explicit directive these days. There is no specific rule about not inlining functions with return statements. This would be pointless anyway because that is the only main difference between macros and inline functions.

Different compilers will generate different code for inline functions with just the `inline` keyword. MSC compiler has a `__forceinline` keyword which will force a function to be inline. Note that indiscriminate inlining will generate more code. These days performance overheads are rarely because of the overhead of a function jump. I would advise you to profile your code and not do any premature optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such rule. However, inline is a request to the compiler to make this as macro if possible, for complex functions, inlining will be ignored and will be just like normal function.